# How to create own modules in Perl

Tags: perl, module

**Module**

```
package ExampleModule;

use strict;
use base "Exporter";
our @export = qw/hello_world/;
sub hello_world
{
    print "Hello,world";
}
1
```

**Test:**

```
 perl -c examplemodule.pm
    examplemodule.pm syntax OK
```

**Script:**

```
use ExampleModule;
hello_world();
exit;
```

but I'm getting error

**Error:**
Can't locate ExampleModule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at until.pl line 229.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at until.pl line 229.

What is the wrong in my Module please let me know

**EDIT**

```
package ExampleModule;

use strict;
use base "Exporter";
our @EXPORT = qw(hello_world);

sub hello_world {
    print "Hello,world";
}
1;
```

saved with ExampleModule.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use lib "/home/Admin/Desktop/Perl_Work_Space/ExampleModule.pm/";
use ExampleModule ;
hell_world();
exit;
```

saved with first.pl

**getting error**

```
[Admin@localhost Perl_Work_Space]$ perl first.pl 
Undefined subroutine &main::hell_world called at first.pl line 5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing path to your module in `@INC`. To fix it you can tell perl where to look for modules,

```
use lib "lib/";  # relative or absolute path to ExampleModule.pm
use ExampleModule;
hello_world();
```

Also `ExampleModule.pm` should have package line at the top, and use but don't inherit `Exporter` module,

```
package ExampleModule;

use strict;
use Exporter "import";
our @EXPORT = qw/hello_world/;

sub hello_world {
    print "Hello,world";
}
1;
```

Comment: how to mention module path in @INC please let me know

Comment: `use lib "/home/Admin/Desktop/Perl_Work_Space/examplemodule.pm/";
use ExampleModule;
hello_world();` but still am getting same error

Comment: then we don't need to add `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`?

Comment: Ok. Now how can use that module? I tried with  `use lib "/home/Admin/Desktop/Perl_Work_Space/examplemodule.pm/"; use ExampleModule; hello_world();`but still getting same error

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `Undefined subroutine &main::hell_world called at module.pl line 5`

Comment: I changed all the changes what you mentioned above but still I'm getting error `Undefined subroutine &main::hell_world called at module.pl line 5.`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `use lib ...;` statement, the packagename and the filename have to have the same spelling including the capitalization. So rename the file to `ExampleModule.pm`.

Although I'm wondering why `perl -c examplemodule.pm` does not emit a warning.

And you have to use `our @EXPORT = qw/hello_world/;`

Comment: I don't know and file name and module name has different capitalization.